# How do you write automated tests for custom bazel rules?

Tags: automated-tests, bazel, bazel-rules

I've been thinking about the best way to write automated tests to validate the bazel rules that we wrote.  The bazel documentation on [testing](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/testing.html) indicates we can use [Skylib](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib) has a test framework called [`unittest.bzl`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/blob/master/lib/unittest.bzl), however that check the analysis-time behaviour of the rule.

In my case, we have rules that spawn a processes, and if the process dies, we expect a certain output. As such, I have created bazel targets that I expect to fails as I want to test some negative path (such as manually killing a process).

I'm looking to test happy path, but really want to test the negative paths, things that can go boom, etc...

I'm just wondering:

- What worked for you and what didn't?
- What techniques/tools/things you used to test the custom rules you wrote in bazel?
- Did you write a bazel target that runs a `sh_test`, which the shell scripts runs bazel and expect a test failure?
- Did you use a new tools? If so, how did you ensure the same version of the tools is used across the organization?
- Did you focus on happy paths, negative paths, or both?

Looking forward to hearing your responses